# Store a mock object in the Environment

Tags: swiftui, combine

In my app, I want to store an object in Environment to perform network queries from various views. However, during development I'd like to use a mock instead, and retrieve the payload (in JSON format) from the app's bundle. These are the steps I've taken:

1. Specify the protocol

```
    typealias Token = String

    protocol MyAPIConforming {
        func signIn(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Token?, Error?) -> Void)
    }
```

2. Implement the two classes I need

```
    class MockMyAPIManager: MyAPIConforming, ObservableObject {
        func signIn(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Token?, Error?) -> Void) {
            // Read the JSON document from the app's bundle
        }
    }

    class MyAPIManager: MyAPIConforming, ObservableObject {
        func signIn(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Token?, Error?) -> Void) {
            // Perform the network request
        }
    }
```

3. Inject the mock object in the Environment

```
    let myManager = MockMyAPIManager()

    // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
    let contentView = LoginView().environmentObject(myManager)
```

4. Declare the @Environment object in the view

```
    struct LoginView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myManager: MyAPIConforming
    ...
```

I did declare `myManager` to be `MyAPIConforming` because I could be passing an object of type `MockMyAPIManager` or `MyAPIManager`.

However, in step #4 I get the following error:

> Property type 'MyAPIConforming' does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'EnvironmentObject'

I'm not sure if the error means that there is no guarantee that the object adopting to `MyAPIConforming` will be also adopting the `ObservableObject` protocol.

So what do I need to do to store either `MockMyAPIManager` or `MyAPIManager` in the environment? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution

```
struct LoginView<T: ObservableObject & MyAPIConforming>: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myManager: T

        // other code here
}
```

**Update:** usage

for content view

```
LoginView<MyAPIManager>().environmentObject(MyAPIManager())
```

and for testing/preview

```
LoginView<MockMyAPIManager>().environmentObject(MockMyAPIManager())
```

Comment: thanks, but if I do that, then I get an error in the call site: `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`. The fix seems to be `let contentView = LoginView<ObservableObject & MyAPIConforming>().environmentObject(myManager)`, but then I get `Value of protocol type 'ObservableObject & MyAPIConforming' cannot conform to 'ObservableObject'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols`.